# Is there a way to bookmark AND close all tabs in Chrome with a single click?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

I checked all the questions asked already about this subject - all of them are about bookmarking all open tabs (CTRL-SHIFT-D in Chrome...), but **none** are about automatically closing them all afterwards.

Is there a way (by script or an extension) to bookmark and immediately close all open tabs (for example, put them all as bookmarks in a new bookmarks folder using the current date/time as the folder name)?

I found an extension that does something similar but it uses it's own facility to save the opened tabs - I want something that uses Chrome's regular bookmarks.

I checked loads of existing Chrome extensions - like OneTab, TabHamster, Bookmark My Tabs, Neater Bookmarks, Bookmarks Menu, Neater Bookmarks, Open Bookmark Manager, TooManyTabs, Goomarks, Papaly Bookmark Manager, Bookmax, Qileke Navigation, Dewey Bookmarks and more - I installed and tested all of them, but none of them do exactly what I'm looking for :/

Comment: Doesn't ctrl shft W close all tabs?

Comment: @Raystafarian yes, but then if I want to bookmark and close all windows I would need to press: ctrl-shift-d, enter, ctrl-shift-w...

Comment: Exactly. Or write yourself a script that pulls those commands

Comment: @Raystafarian right, but I don't know how to write scripts for Chrome, and I couldn't find how to do it (or more  precisely, I found too much information and didn't manage to filter it to exactly what I need without spending hours learning...) :)

Comment: If you don't want to learn, you might want to post to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ with requirements, they may know of an extension that does this.

Comment: @Raystafarian cheers, I'll try that. I would love to learn how to do it btw. I just don't have time to sift through hours of material to find how to run Chrome commands in a script. I really tried searching for it, but I guess it's not that easy when you don't know exactly what to look for. Any leads or hints would be much appreciated though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TidyTab does the job with 2 clicks. It's like OneTab with bookmark saving.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidytab/lkglfdjcamhjoggmabobhggmpfjhccff

Comment: Can you explain about this extension?

Comment: Cool, it indeed does the job, thanks! I'm wondering though about the extensive permissions it requires - why does it need to "read and change all the data on the websites you visit"...?

Comment: Permissions are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the TidyTab is 'Error 404' now, I'd like to recommend Abookmark.

Abookmark is a chrome extension which adds more advanced features to the native bookmark system. It can store tabs into bookmarks and close the tabs at the same time just as you want. You can store all tabs, current tab, tabs on the right, etc...

There are some shortcuts to do this. And it has a toolbar about these.