# Google Chrome - automatically bookmark all the open tabs before exiting chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, browser-tabs, tabs

When I close or exit from chrome, I want to save all the open tabs automatically to bookmarks(or something else); and when I re-open chrome, by clicking on the extension(or something else), I would like to open all the tabs that were saved in previous session when I had closed and when I close chrome again, I would like previous save session to be overwritten with current tabs.

Put simply, I would like to simulate "where you left off" option from "On startup" in Settings, since I can't change that setting on my work computer.

How do I do this?

My google chrome Version: `87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)` for Enterrpise on Windows 10 for Enterprise. And I am a user of this computer, who can't change settings to open chrome "where you left off" and doing ctrl+shift+D is taking time and it's highly likely that I forget to do it some times.

This question is different from: [Is there a way to bookmark AND close all tabs in Chrome with a single click?](https://superuser.com/questions/898320/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-and-close-all-tabs-in-chrome-with-a-single-click)

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is really late but maybe it might help somebody.

I use extension Tab Session Manager (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-session-manager/iaiomicjabeggjcfkbimgmglanimpnae?hl=en)

It saves all opened windows and tabs in regular intervals and on window closing. Basically it makes snapshot of your opened windows and tabs and later you can browse all these snapshots and restore separate tabs or windows.

screenshot of its interface

[image]

I usually have opened about 5 chrome windows, each with 20+ tabs and I use this extension as a safety net, in case I close some window I didn't want to close, or in case there is some problems with reopening where I left after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the meat of this trick: to save all the tabs you currently have open, right-click on the tab bar and select “Bookmark all tabs” from the popup menu. The Bookmark all tabs dialog box displays.

Comment: which is what ctrl+shift+D does and I may forget doing and want to be done automatically when i exit out of chrome.